# Removing extra decimals in Python operations

Tags: python, decimal

I want to do operations like

500.55%10 and get a value of 0.55 in return.

But instead Python sometimes returns 0.5500000000000114 for example (which in terms of magnitude is basically the same), I'm guessing this is because of the numerical way these calculations are done.

When I input a value like 500.55 I want it to be seen as 500.55000000000000.... with an infinite amount of zeros.  So basically I want to get rid of ...00114 at the end.

```
print(500.55%10)
0.5500000000000114
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try reading more about the built-in [`decimal` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#quick-start-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `round` function to round. Alternatively you need to use the `decimal` module which handles extra decimals in the way that you ask...

here are both methods:

```py
import decimal

# normal way
print('normal way:', 500.55%10)   

# do some rounding
print('rounding:', round(500.55%10, 10) )

# use the decimal
decimal.getcontext().prec = 10
print('decimal module:',  decimal.Decimal(500.55)%decimal.Decimal(10))
```

result:

```
normal way: 0.5500000000000114
rounding: 0.55
decimal module: 0.5500000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `decimal` module:

```py
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> float(Decimal('500.55') % 10)
0.55
```

Documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#quick-start-tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the built-in [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module and their [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) object.

```
decimal.Decimal(value='0', context=None)
```

from the documentation:

> Construct a new Decimal object based from value.
>
> value can be an integer, string, tuple, [float](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float), or another `Decimal` object. If no value is given, returns `Decimal('0')`. If value is a string, it should conform to the decimal numeric string syntax after leading and trailing whitespace characters, as well as underscores throughout, are removed

Example implementation:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> float(decimal.Decimal('500.55') % 10)
0.55
```